# Make 2 streams of particles that clash in the middle and change colors

Tags: particles

I want to use the "make instances real" option to make a mesh of all my particles from a particles system.

The setup is; 1 cube with particles system which is emitting the particles falling onto a plane that has a collision modifier on it. All works fine, but now I want the particles to not only interact with the floor plane, but also with other particles. And particles from other emitters.

But I can't find the "make instances real" option (in the collision tab) anymore.
See image below.

[image]

My general idea is to have 2 "streams" of particles enter from the left and right part of the screen (outside camera view) and make all particles from both sides (emitters) interact/collide/clash when they all meet in the middle of the screen. And when all particles from both emitters meet in the middle they change color.

The video in the link below is for reference.. so the sort of particles, flow, changing of colors etc is what I want kind of the same. Only this example is filling up a invisible sphere and I want 2 streams clashing in the middle.

https://youtu.be/G5CkRDhOwx0

Or is there a better/different way of doing this? Maybe using geometry nodes particles? Or force field particles?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all: you say you have particles there. _Make Instances Real_ is only available if you instance any object on those particles, like a sphere for example. That's why it is not called "make particles real".  When there are instances, then this option converts the instances into real separate mesh objects. The other thing is (but you probably know this already), making them real does not automatically make them interact with each other. For that you need to make them rigid bodies for example. But they do not inherit the movement of the particles.

Comment: Thnx for your quick reply! Ah yea my bad, I was following a tut that does this, but the tut maker was using intances (Letters) that where replacing the particles :). So his way is not working for me cause I am not using instances but real particles.

But you might have a suggestion on how I could create what I describe using just real particles? Or do I have for example should use the tut makers way and use a sphere as an instance where he uses letters?

Comment: Making the particles force fields could work, it depends on tweaking the settings so that it looks more or less natural I guess... Vey important to set a _Max Distance_ for the _Falloff_ so that they only influence each other when close enough.

Comment: you could have a look at the molecular add-on. This gives the particles a "kind of" rigid body. At least they are all reacting on each other (colliding). It's really powerful.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Ok I will check that out idd. Would this be your preferred method of trying to get what I described? Or maybe looking into the molecular + add-on that Chris is referring to?

Comment: @Chris Thnx for the suggestion, I already had the molecular + add-on in my mind cause it came by when searching for good tuts on solving my "problem". But hadn't checked the add-ons possibilities better cause I was thinking that using 2 of the basic particles system on both sides spitting out particles to the middle should also do the trick right? Just how to make the particles interact with each other when meeting in the middle (bounce, stick, change colors) isnt still clear to me.

Comment: Well I haven't used the _Molecular_ addon for a long time because I haven't been doing many particle animations in the past few years. I always thought it is a great and promising addon but my hardware was too bad to handle it back then. Nowadays it would probably be much better but as I said, haven't done much particle stuff recently. @Chris is much more experienced with some addons than me, so maybe you should give it a try.